# How to configure journald to discard entries older than a certain time span

Tags: systemd-journald, journalctl

From the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) I know that I can configure

1. the time after which journal *files* are deleted via `MaxRetentionSec`.
2. the time after which journal *files* are rotated via `MaxFileSec`.

However my goal is to configure journald in a way such that all journal entries are stored within one file for a time span of one year. Older *entries* should be discarded.

My current workaround is that I have

- `MaxRetentionSec=1year`
- `MaxFileSec=1month`

This has, however, two major disadvantages.

1. The journal is rotated after every month such that accessing older entries is a hassle.
2. Journald will discard a whole month every time the year expires instead of just, let's say, one day.

Is it possible to configure the journal to behave as described in the goal?

Answer (score 5):

Just found this brilliant answer on the askubuntu stackexchange: https://askubuntu.com/a/1012913/36168

To recap, the author suggests setting up a cronjob to run on a periodic basis, e.g for your use case, run this daily:

```
$ journalctl --vacuum-time=1y
```

Ref:

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html#--vacuum-size=

Comment: Using `SystemMaxUse` would be more brilliant than cron-ing a temporary fix.

Comment: How does `SystemMaxUse` help the OP, the question is about preserve the logs for a period of time, rather than limit by size use... or have I misread something?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `MaxRetentionSec`.

Comment: This does not answer the question - the OP secifically does not want to delete files, but entries within a file.

Comment: [journald.conf.htm](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#)

Answer (score 2):

> However my goal is to configure journald in a way such that all journal entries are stored within one file for a time span of one year.

That means the file would rotate after 1 year, and be deleted after the last entry is more than 1 year old.

There is no way to do what you want. You have to do as with `syslog` and `logrotate`: rotate to several files, and delete the oldest ones. If you don't want to waste space for a month load of log, you rotate more often.

> The journal is rotated after every month such that accessing older entries is a hassle

How is that? The `journalctl` utility reads all available journal files seamlessly.